# Is there way to dynamically click bind every word in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to bind every word in an element without actually changing the markup in the element with Javascript

Comment: Alright, where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can't bind an event listener to a textNode.

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Bind an event to the div itsself, then wrap each word in a span so you have individual elements that can be an event.target. There's probably some way to do it with mouse position and string length, but that sounds even more complicated.

Comment: @charlietfl I am building a chrome extension and thats is highlighting words in certain sites textarea. For certain sites textarea are built so they will not allow words to be wrapped in html , So i have created a clone that matches every word and highlighting is being displayed, my only issue the highlighted words are not clickable because the sites main textarea is blocking it.

Comment: Wrapping words in spans is most common approach and easy to do

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: No.

If you REALLY wanted to do this, I suppose you could write a script that went through the div and manually added the markup for you. And then you could add click events to the automatically added markup.

But then you would just be writing a script that adds the markup you don't want to.

So long answer: No, not without adding markup in some context.

Comment: It is possible by using parent, just depends on what use case is

Comment: To bind a click event to a single word within a element without additional markup? I don't believe so.

Comment: @charlietfl How would it be possible to bind individual words that make up the content of an element without separating those words into child elements? Why would the use case have anything to do with how to achieve this?

Comment: @ScottMarcus again, depends on use case but can get caret position inside parent element and evaluate what word it ends up on

Comment: @charlietfl That is widely unsupported and not standard.

Comment: @BryantJackson In my use case i cannot add markup I know which words need to be bound, would there be a way to track there postion and add a click event that way?